# Valuing items based on odds

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics

Say I'm buying a pack of cards for `$4`.

The pack contains 5 cards, though I don't think this really impacts the scenario.

***Simple Scenario***

In a simple scenario, a pack might have a single type of insert that has 1:2 odds for a 50/50 chance at opening a pack with an insert in it.

In this scenario I would value an insert at `$8` because that's how much it would cost me on average to get an insert and I'm valuing the base cards at `$0`.

***Complex Scenario***

In the more complex scenario, the pack has the following odds:

Type A) 1:1 - Guaranteed to get one and only one of this type

Type B) 1:3

Type C) 1:5

Type Z) ~ The default base you get if it's not one of the above cards

You will never get 2 of a single type in a pack. It's possible to get types A, B, & C all in a single pack.

**QUESTION: What is the value of each type of card?**

If I bought 100 packs at `$4`, I spent `$400` and would expect (on average) to have received:

100 Type A cards

33 Type B cards

20 Type C cards

But I don't know how to divide & assign that `$400` to these 153 cards as they don't seem like they should have equal weight.

My napkin math says divide total money spent by number of types 
`400/3 = 133.33`

Then divide that by number of cards

```
133.33/100 = 1.33
133.33/33 = 4.04
133.33/20 = 6.66
```

Not sure if that seems right though.

Comment: This is not determined.  Maybe type $A$ cards are worth $4$ and no other card has any value, just for one example.  Or maybe type $B$ cards are worth $12$ each and no other card has any value.  And so on.

Comment: I think you are thinking about it backwards.  The value to you of $A,B,C$ cards is independent of the price of a pack.  You need to establish it by other means.  The calculation you are doing is what you do to determine whether to buy a pack or not.  If you and the pack seller are reacting to the same market, so you know the price of a packet is fair, you still have one equation in three unknowns, so cannot determine the market price of any one of them.

Comment: I'm not asking about free market conditions.  A question like this has to make some assumptions, so the answers have to abide by the assumptions.  I'm assuming a perfect market.  I'm assuming something that has a greater rarity, defined by a lower probability of acquisition, is worth more than a card that is easier to acquire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a unique answer to this question.  If $a,b,c$ are the values of types A,B,C, respectively, all that we can say is that $$100a+33b+20c=400\tag1$$  There are infinitely many solutions to this equation.  I didn't completely follow the logic behind the method you used, but the way I did it came up with the same answer you did.

I would think that type C is worth $5$ times as much as type A, and type B is worth $3$ times as much, so we would get $$\begin{align}300a&=400\tag2\\
a&=\frac43\approx1.33,\\b&=4\\c&=\frac{20}3\approx6.67\end{align}$$
Note that in $(1)$ I rounded $33.\overline{3}$ off to $33$ as you did, but in deriving $(2)$ I used the true value.  That accounts for the slight differences from your values.

Others may find different valuations more appropriate.